# $F_X=\lambda F_{X_{d}}+(1-\lambda)F_{X_{c}}$: Conditions on $f_X$ for $F_X$ to be a distribution?

Tags: calculus, probability

Let's suppose we have $I_i=]a_{i-1},a_i[, i\in \{1,...,n\}$, with $a_0=-\infty$ and $a_n=+\infty$.

Let $f$ be continuous on its domain which is $\bigcup_{i \in \{1,...,n\}}I_i$. With $F(x)=\int^x_{a_0}f(u) du$.

Let $F_X=\lambda F_{X_{d}}+(1-\lambda)F_{X_{c}}$, where $X_{d}$ is a discrete r.v. with mass points at the $a_i$'s, and $X_{c}$ is a continuous r.v. and $\lambda \in ]0,1[$?

If I want to be sure that $F_X$ is distribution function, what conditions must $f_X$ satisfy?

Let's assume I'm using Riemann integrals. I'm interested in answers assuming knowledge only of calculus and 1st probability course.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No conditions (except the obvious: positivity and complete integral equal to 1). A convex combination of cdfs is a cdf.

Answer (score 0):

A cumulative distribution function ([CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)) $\Phi$ must have the following properties:

1. non-decreasing, i.e. $y\geq x\implies \Phi(y)\geq \Phi(x)$;
2. right-continuous, i.e. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0\\ x>x_0}\Phi(x) = \Phi(x_0)$;
3. has limit $0$ at $-\infty$;
4. has limit $1$ at $+\infty$.

For every pair of CDFs $(F_{X_d}, F_{X_c})$, all properties 1.-4. are satisfied by $F_{X_d}$ and $F_{X_c}$. Using the definitions, one shows that every convex linear combination $\lambda F_{X_d} + (1-\lambda) F_{X_c}$ with $\lambda \in \left[0,1\right]$ of two CDFs $F_{X_d}$ and $F_{X_c}$ is a CDF (independently on the type of variables ${X_d}$ and ${X_c}$). As specified in the comments, the distribution $f_X$ defined by $F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X$ just needs to satisfy the non-negativity and $\int_\Bbb{R} f_X = 1$ properties, since $F_X$ is already a CDF.

Comment: Harry, thanks for the info. However, I don't think it answers the question. What conditions must f_x satisfy?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: zhoraster in the main comment and Harry49 have already answered your question. No additional condition to those already provided by  $(F_{X_d}, F_{X_c})$ being CDF's is needed as $F_X$ is already a CDF. For general $f$ is a nonnegative distribution (generalized function) integrating to $1$.